# Using CSS3 background-size cover. As this uses a css url for the image, is it possible to get it fullscreen on IE8 and older?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am using css3 to get a nice full-screen background image.

```
body{ 
  background: url(<?php echo $background_image; ?>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Of course IE8 and older do not play ball and look terrible. Is there a simple way to get it working on IE8?

I looked at [jQuery AnyStretch](https://github.com/danmillar/jquery-anystretch), which is called using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.anystretch(<?php echo $background_image; ?>, {speed: 150});
</script>
```

but even though it works, I couldn't make it so it only loaded in IE8 browsers. With anystretch, the browser loads the image twice (once in css and once for the html  created by anystretch).

Anyone have any ideas on a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check this site out [CSS Tricks Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). It covers different techniques to use as fallbacks for browsers that do not support CSS3 properties such as `background-size`. It has both CSS only methods and jQuery assisted methods.

CSS Only Technique #2 covers IE8+ fallbacks

Comment: I might end up doing that. My only issue is that I wanted to use ccs3 as it is the most elegant and simple solution and then add some sort of fallback for the crap browsers (ie).

Comment: you can do exactly that, use CSS3 and fallback for IE, etc

Comment: How do you mean? The IE filters aren't working for me, they make the images stretch badly. And the non-ccs3 require a separate <img>

Comment: put the CSS3 in a stylesheet for example called style.css and put the fallback CSS in a stylesheet for example called old.css and call to it like so `<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="old.css" /><![endif]-->` this will target IE8 and lower versions

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "simple' way. Most just choose an alternative background for older browsers, such as a gradient image with repeat-x.

Answer (score 0):

> but even though it works, I couldn't make it so it only loaded in IE8
>   browsers.

This will only load in IE 8 browsers:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.anystretch(<?php echo $background_image; ?>, {speed: 150});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

or if you want it to load on IE 8 and lower:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.anystretch(<?php echo $background_image; ?>, {speed: 150});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
background:url("image.png")no-repeat;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="image.png",sizingMethod=scale);
-ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="image.png",sizingMethod=scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how hacky you wanna get. You could place the css in a media query, so it won't load in IE8 or older (because they don't support media queries). Then place conditional comments around the javascript to specifically target IE 8 or earlier (as shown by Alex W). This way you only let IE8 or older use the anyStretch functionality, and avoid loading the image twice for those browsers.